# Index into std_logic_vector using signal

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl

I need to modify a certain portion of a register, but the upper and lower bound of the modified part depend on the input. Can the following code:

(1) be synthesised?

(2) if so, what circuit do the tools produce?

```
reg (to_integer (unsigned(upper1)) downto to_integer (unsigned(lower1)))
 <= input (to_integer (unsigned(upper2)) downto to_integer (unsigned(lower2));
```

(edit: the syntax might be wrong, but I hope I've got the idea across)

Comment: Hint: multiplexers..

Comment: Any time you see that many type conversions, step back and declare things in the right type in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for every reg bit to be fed by any of the input bits as long as *upper1*, *lower1*, *upper2* and *lower2* are within the **range** of the respective vvectors.

Note that any **reg** bits that aren't specified by the range between *upper1* and *lower1* will be unchanged (forming a **latch** in a combinatorial implementation e.g. concurrent assignment or an unchanged output of a flipflop in a sequential design e.g. clocked process) and any of the input bits not covered in the range of *upper2* to *lower2* will be ignored.

As Eugene_Sh commented, it will be done using multiplexers.